# Table HTML from Google sheets with hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I have an online spreadsheet on google and created an html page that shows the spreadsheet table. The problem is that the contents of a column are links and the html table does not show those clickable links. I have found many solutions on the internet, but all of them are including a fixed link in the code. My table receives data and each row has a different link. How can I do this?

Following is a part of the code I executed :

```
    <br><br>
     
    <table id = "Tab">
    
  <thead>
    <tr>
         <th class= "Titulo">Nº de inscrição</th>
         <th class= "Titulo">CPF</th>
         <th class= "Titulo">Nº de cadastro</th>
         <th class= "Titulo">Link</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
     
     <tbody id = "CorpoTabela">
     
     </tbody>
  
    </table>
   
    </div>
   </div>
    
    
    <?!=Chamar("Tabela-js")?>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **anchor tag** inside your `<th>` tag. You can enter your link in `href` field like so:

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

Where `#` is your link.

Comment: I can't determine the link because I don't know the link.  The table is constantly fed and each row of a given column has a link.  So, I need the HTML code to identify that all cells in that column are links.

Answer (score 0):

I can't determine the link because I don't know the link.  The table is constantly fed and each row of a given column has a link.  So, I need the HTML code to identify that all cells in that column are links.